# Identifying the presence of specific factors across multiple categories of data table in R

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am using R and trying to determine patients who have specific diagnoses from claim lines of an imported data table. If diagnosis code(s) are in the claim, then classify them with an indicator in a new column in the same data table. A patient can have many diagnoses columns (>50) in a single claim table.

In this particular example I am only showing 6 diagnosis columns, and looking specifically for claims containing diagnoses codes "25000" or "25001" (for some diseases like cancer there can be hundreds of different diagnoses codes).

#### Example claim file

```
ID <- c(01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06)
Dx1 <- c('25000', '25000', '91260', '87940', '81930', '79020')
Dx2 <- c('49600', '77760', '25000', '39320', '66020', '40100')
Dx3 <- c('41000', '49600', '65120', '65400', '40100', '88730')
Dx4 <- c('83500', '65940', '43100', '95210', '44000', '80390')
Dx5 <- c('58450', '25001', '81930', '35080', '49040', '40100')
Dx6 <- c('95260', '49600', '96460', "25000", '27910', '33720')
mydata <- data.frame(ID,Dx1,Dx2,Dx3,Dx4,Dx5,Dx6)
```

#### Look for a specific diagnoses codes across the claim

```
mydata2 <- mydata[mydata$Dx1 %in% c('25000', "25001")
|  mydata$Dx2 %in% c('25000', "25001")
|  mydata$Dx3 %in% c('25000', "25001")
|  mydata$Dx4 %in% c('25000', "25001")
|  mydata$Dx5 %in% c('25000', "25001")
|  mydata$Dx6 %in% c('25000', "25001"), ]
```

#### Create new indicator column

```
mydata$Diab <- ifelse(mydata$ID %in% (mydata2$ID), 1, 0)
```

I successfully created an indicator using multiple "or" statements, but this can be very cumbersome with many diagnoses columns in the claim data table, I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this instead of using repeating "or" statements?

Comment: I would advice to reshape your data and to `ID`, `DxN`, `value` columns. Then It would much easier to do a lot of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[ , Diab := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) any(x %in% c("25000","25001")))]
```

And if you really wanted `integer`s instead of `logical`, just use the "cheater `+`":

```
mydata[ , Diab := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) +any(x %in% c("25000","25001")))]
```

Comment: blows my mind - it took me 15 minutes to create the question and you answered in 13 minutes!!, thanks so much! - if I could ask, could you elaborate on "cheater +"?

Comment: @RobertWhite you'll get there soon enough :)

Comment: it's sort of a quirk of the R interpreter that if you prepend a logical vector with `+`,  it's interpreted as adding your vector to 0... and adding, in turn, forces the logical type into an integer. essentially it's (more or less) equivalent to `as.integer` but more concise.

Comment: Pretty nice "trick" - again, thank you!!!! - you just reduced about 3000 lines of code from my work!

Comment: @RobertWhite also keep in mind what jangorecki said. `apply` is actually relatively slow -- there are much faster options available if your data is in long format.

Comment: you sparked my interest, while I am not in need of fast results, I am curious about alternatives..since you mentioned it B-)